# Pig script new record

Tags: apache-pig, latin

I am working on following mail data in a file.. `(data source:infochimps)`

`Message-ID: <33025919.1075857594206.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
Date: Wed, 13 Dec 2000 13:09:00 -0800 (PST)
From: john.arnold@enron.com
To: slafontaine@globalp.com
Subject: re:spreads
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: John Arnold
X-To: slafontaine@globalp.com @ ENRON
X-cc: 
X-bcc: 
X-Folder: \John_Arnold_Dec2000\Notes Folders\'sent mail
X-Origin: Arnold-J
X-FileName: Jarnold.nsf`

saw a lot of the bulls sell summer against length in front to mitigate 
margins/absolute position limits/var.  as these guys are taking off the 
front, they are also buying back summer.  el paso large buyer of next winter 
today taking off spreads.  certainly a reason why the spreads were so strong 
on the way up and such a piece now.   really the only one left with any risk 
premium built in is h/j now.   it was trading equivalent of 180 on access, 
down 40+ from this morning.  certainly if we are entering a period of bearish

................]

I am loading above data as:-

`A = load '/root/test/enron_mail/maildir/*/*/*' using PigStorage(':') as (f1:chararray,f2:chararray);`

but for the message body I am getting separate tuples as message body includes new lines..

how to consolidate last lines into one ?
I want below part in single tuple as:

saw a lot of the bulls sell summer against length in front to mitigate 
margins/absolute position limits/var.  as these guys are taking off the 
front, they are also buying back summer.  el paso large buyer of next winter 
today taking off spreads.  certainly a reason why the spreads were so strong 
on the way up and such a piece now.   really the only one left with any risk 
premium built in is h/j now.   it was trading equivalent of 180 on access, 
down 40+ from this morning.  certainly if we are entering a period of bearish

Comment: have you considered using REPLACE function (http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/REPLACE.html) to replace newline chars with something else?

Comment: If each input is a file then you can use some shell script to replace the newlines before feeding it to pig script, or you have to write a UDF to load data.

Comment: Ok, suppose I replace newline with some character e.g comma (,). then how does Pig script recognize new record?